# Who came up with "nothing propinks like propinquity"?

Tags: etymology, aphorism

The *Online Etymology Dictionary* entry for the verb [*to approach*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=approach) references [*propinquity*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=propinquity) ([*NED*](http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/1476/mode/1up), [*psychology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propinquity), [*AHD*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=propinquity), [*wiktionary*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propinquity)) which contains a reference to an aphorism:

> late 14c., "nearness in relation, kinship," later also "physical
> nearness" (early 15c.), from Old French [*propinquite*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/dictionnaire-godefroy/437/6/propinquit%C3%A9) (13c.) and
> directly from Latin *propinquitatem* (nominative [*propinquitas*](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.14:5637.lewisandshort))
> "nearness, vicinity; relationship, affinity," from [*propinquus*](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.14:5639.lewisandshort) "near,
> neighboring," from *prope* "near" (enlarged from PIE *pro "before;"
> see pro-) + suffix *-inquus*.
>
> **Nothing propinks like propinquity** [Ian Fleming, **chapter heading**, "Diamonds are Forever," 1956; phrase popularized 1960s by U.S.
> diplomat George Ball ]
>
> [ *Online Etymology Dictionary* - n.b. added links ]

---

> He often used the aphorism (perhaps originally coined by Ian Fleming
> in *Diamonds are Forever*) "Nothing propinks like propinquity," later
> dubbed the *Ball Rule of Power*. It means that the more direct
> access you have to the president, the greater your power, no matter
> what your title actually is.
>
> [Wikipedia @ [*George Ball*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Ball_%28diplomat%29#Positions), note omitted]

On *Books* the [*Diamonds are Forever*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamonds_Are_Forever_%28novel%29) can be found (such as  [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=A08oBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT140&dq=Diamonds%20are%20Forever%20%20fleming%20propinquity&pg=PT140#v=onepage&q=propinks&f=false) with the cover of [*The Diamonds Smugglers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diamond_Smugglers), which is Mr Fleming's non-fiction work from the research for the novel); in it, there is the aforementioned heading. When you scroll a few pages down, you have the following:

> [Felix]Leiter Chuckled. "Come on lovebirds," he said, looking at his
> watch. We ought to get going. I've got to get back to Vegas tonight
> and start looking at the skeleton of our dear dumb friend Shy Smile.
> And you've got your 'plane to catch. You can go one quarreling at
> twenty thousand feet. Get a better perspective from there. May even
> decide to make up and be friends. You know what they say" - he
> beckoned to the waiter - "nothing propinks like propinquity."
> [...]
>  Bond knew that he was very near to being in love with this
> girl.[...]
>
> [Ian Fleming, *Diamonds are Forever*, 26 March 1956/UK]

I don't know the novels, but Felix making some sort of insinuation is not necessarily out of character from what I remember of the movies; I construe the reference as such. But for a U.S. diplomat of the (President)Eisenhower era to be using exactly that and then having the *Ball Rule of Power* being coined after it strikes me as somewhat odd. Or is it?

---

Who came up with "*nothing propinks like propinquity*" (if not for Mr Fleming); is that "heading" from the novel really the basis for Mr Ball using it and for the *Ball Rule of Power* being coined?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: It is undoubtedly a sexual joke in the [James Bond books and movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Bond). They're noted for this.

Comment: The basic construction is at least a couple of centuries old. This from 1813: [*According to the proverb, successful treason is never treason, because “**nothing succeeds like success**," as Sir J. Harrington sang :  “Treason doth never prosper: what 's the reason? For if it prosper, none dare call it treason."*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nothing+succeeds+like+success%22&biw=1385&bih=890&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1815&tbm=bks)

Comment: It should be noted that some similar phrases are attributed to P.G. Wodehouse. https://books.google.com/books?id=YUWj6uKYHM4C&pg=PT80&lpg=PT80&dq=%22Nothing+propinks+like+propinquity%22&source=bl&ots=PKWZExHbj5&sig=KcS8r0Y7r2wYd9XO1oURoM_bIUs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MC1RVZKJNoHZsAW1tYCoDw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwBDgU#v=onepage&q=%22Nothing%20propinks%20like%20propinquity%22&f=false and http://aislnews.org/?p=1855

Comment: The phrase is also attributed to Dorothy Parker via a [couple of sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dorothy+parker%22+%22like+propinquity%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: Something I'd missed up to this point is that "propink" is not a "real" word (though "propinque" apparently is, albeit incredibly archaic).

Comment: (But unfortunately "propinque" is an incredibly common Latin word, so searching is difficult at best.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though Ian Fleming is the first author to have used the expression, "Nothing propinks like propinquity." A Google Books search for *propinks* strikes out on anything older than 1956, as does a Library of Congress newspaper search for the word *propinks* across the period 1836–1922.

The online attributions to P.G. Wodehouse seem based on a conversation in *Right Ho, Jeeves* in which Jeeves suggests *propinquity* as the word Bertie Wooster is trying to think of, and Bertie confirms that it is. (The conversation appears on the [Association of Independent Librarians page](http://aislnews.org/?p=1855) that Hot Licks links to in a comment above.) None of the online attributions of the quotation "Nothing propinks like propinquity" either to Wodehouse or to Dorothy Parker that a Google Books search turns up identify a page in the author's work where the expression appears. This is a warning sign (though not a definitive proof in the negative) of false attribution.

The only quotations involving propinquity that make their way into *The Oxford Book of Quotations*, third edition (1979) are from Shakespeare, *King Lear*:

> Here I disclaim all my paternal care,/Propinquity and property of blood,/And as a stranger to my heart and me/Hold thee from this for ever.

and from Mrs. Humphrey Ward, *Robert Elsmere* (1888):

> 'Propinquity does it'—as Mrs. Thornburgh is always reminding us.

The quote from *Robert Elsmere* has much in common with "Nothing propinks..." as an idea, but I don't think that Ian Fleming owes her any royalties on the wording he devised.

Comment: I did some searching in Google Books on "Wodehouse" and "propinquity" and it turns out that "propinquity" was one of his favorite words -- probably at least a dozen, maybe two dozen mentions.  But I could find nothing coming close to the entire phrase.